# Compiler Error Message: CS1061

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting Compiler Error Message: CS1061:

'ASP.rinatup_registrationforms_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'CheckBox1_CheckedChanged' and no extension method 'CheckBox1_CheckedChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.rinatup_registrationforms_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**RegistrationForms.aspx**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="AnotherMahzorCheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red" Text="Sign up" 
OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Visible="False" />
```

**RegistrationForms.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The user selected to register his child for another Mahzor
        string s = this.NewCourseRadioButtonList.SelectedValue;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "showPanel();", true);
        this.NewCourseRadioButtonList.SelectedValue = s;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScriptB", "showSecondPanel();", true);
        AnotherMahzorCheckBox.Visible = false;
        LocationPanelB.Focus();

    }
```

Help?

Comment: if my solution worked for you please mark it as answer so that others know it works

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is clean your pagename.aspx designer file. Open up the designer file and clean all the contents of it. Then what you need to do is change something in the aspx page. This will ensure new designer code is generate therefore you should not have the issue anymore.